# How to clean a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

**My current DataFrame is given below:**

```
    0   1    2   3      4    5
0   NAN Name NAN Amount NAN Percentage
1   NAN A    NAN 28223  NAN 8.70%
2   NAN B    NAN NAN    NAN NAN
3   NAN C    NAN NAN    NAN NAN
4   NAN D    NAN 21871  NAN 6.80%
5   NAN E    NAN NAN    NAN NAN
6   NAN F    NAN NAN    NAN NAN
7   NAN G    NAN 21380  NAN 6.64%
8   NAN H    NAN NAN    NAN NAN
9   NAN I    NAN NAN    NAN NAN
10  NAN J    NAN 20784  NAN 6.46%
11  NAN K    NAN NAN    NAN NAN
12  NAN L    NAN NAN    NAN NAN
```

I want to clean this DataFrame by removing some of the `NAN` values and some `NAN` values to `Not Listed`.

**Expected Output**

```
Name Amount     Percentage
A    28223      8.70%
B    Not Listed Not Listed
C    Not Listed Not Listed
D    21871      6.80%
E    Not Listed Not Listed
F    Not Listed Not Listed
G    21380      6.64%
H    Not Listed Not Listed
I    Not Listed Not Listed
J    20784      6.46%
K    Not Listed Not Listed
L    Not Listed Not Listed
```

Can someone please Help me on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can drop the unwanted columns by `df.drop([column_names],axis=1)` and replace `NAN` with `not listed` , then set the column headers and drop the extra row which was taken for the header.

```
df =df.drop([0,2,4],axis=1).replace(np.nan, 'Not Listed')
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df.drop(0,inplace=True)
```

Comment: I tried your method, but even this code is not replacing `NAN` to `Not Listed`. I dont understand what I'm missing over here.

Comment: out of curiosity, I'm asking, If I want to remove row also what should I do.
I tried: `df =df.drop([0,1,2],axis=0)` but its not working

Comment: are you getting any error? , if you are trying to drop the row `0` after my code , you will face an error since the row`0` is already dropped. :)

Comment: that part I figured it out. I used `df1 = df1.drop(df1.index[[0, 1, 2]])`
But I'm getting an error on this line `df1.drop(0,inplace=True)`
`Error: KeyError: '[0] not found in axis'`

Comment: So if what to put `inplace = true` for both `column` and `index` what should I do?

Comment: seems like row `0` is not there anymore in your `df1` can you check once by pinting `df1` , `Error: KeyError: '[0] not found in axis'` means there is no row which is labelled as 0.

Comment: Basically the `df1` has no row which has an index named as 0.

Comment: yeah , that is coz I just dropped row of 0,1, 2 , Now I need to put `inplace = true`. How do I do that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186255/discussion-between-anky-91-and-vrinda).

Answer (score 2):

#### `dropna` + `slicing`

```
t = df.dropna(axis=1, how='all').values
pd.DataFrame(t[1:], columns=t[0]).fillna('Not listed')
```

```
   Name      Amount  Percentage
0     A       28223       8.70%
1     B  Not listed  Not listed
2     C  Not listed  Not listed
3     D       21871       6.80%
4     E  Not listed  Not listed
5     F  Not listed  Not listed
6     G       21380       6.64%
7     H  Not listed  Not listed
8     I  Not listed  Not listed
9     J       20784       6.46%
10    K  Not listed  Not listed
11    L  Not listed  Not listed
```

Answer (score 1):

Given your specific structure of the data:

```
df.columns = df.iloc[0, :]  # Rename the columns based on the first row of data.
df.columns.name = None  # Set the columns name to None.
df = df.iloc[1:, :].reset_index(drop=True)  # Drop the column names from the data in the dataframe.
>>> df.replace('NAN', np.nan).dropna(how='all', axis=1).replace(np.nan, 'Not Listed')
   Name      Amount  Percentage
0     A       28223       8.70%
1     B  Not Listed  Not Listed
2     C  Not Listed  Not Listed
3     D       21871       6.80%
4     E  Not Listed  Not Listed
5     F  Not Listed  Not Listed
6     G       21380       6.64%
7     H  Not Listed  Not Listed
8     I  Not Listed  Not Listed
9     J       20784       6.46%
10    K  Not Listed  Not Listed
11    L  Not Listed  Not Listed
```

You could set the index to the name if you wish by changing the last line of code:

```
>>> >>> df.replace('NAN', np.nan).dropna(how='all', axis=1).replace(np.nan, 'Not Listed').set_index('Name')
          Amount  Percentage
Name                        
A          28223       8.70%
B     Not Listed  Not Listed
C     Not Listed  Not Listed
D          21871       6.80%
E     Not Listed  Not Listed
F     Not Listed  Not Listed
G          21380       6.64%
H     Not Listed  Not Listed
I     Not Listed  Not Listed
J          20784       6.46%
K     Not Listed  Not Listed
L     Not Listed  Not Listed
```